# How or where to install Python plugins in OSX? (QGIS 2.18)

Tags: qgis, installation, qgis-2, plugins, apple

For a school assignment we are using QGIS 2.18 (professor's suggestion) and 2 plugins he gave us. I am working on an iMac. The short manual he gave us is for use of QGIS under Windows.

I have QGIS 2.18 installed, now I need to put the plugins in a place the program knows where to look for. Does anybody have a clue how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your user home folder then `.qgis2/python/plugins`.

A folder starting by a dot is a hidden folder on Mac and Linux. So you might need to enable your file browser to see this folder called `.qgis2`.

But you should suggest to your professor that QGIS 2 is not maintained for more than a year now. QGIS 3.10 is out ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I can't add a .qgis2 folder to my user home folder, osx tells me only programs can do that. I can't find a .qgis2 folder on my mac either.

We were specifically instructed to download 2.18 for the purpose of the class. So I think the prof is aware. 

So I am kinda stuck still, about where to put the plugins....

Comment: Install a plugin from QGIS, anyone. Maybe it will create that folder. It seems strange.

Comment: I did and it showed me it was installed just where it should be: .qgis2/etc etc. But I still couldn't find it. 
Then it hit me: Apple has a default of hiding certain files and folders!!! And I didn't need to disable that until now. Googled the shortcut: https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/show-hidden-files-mac-3520878/

It worked! I can now see the .qgis2 folder!!! Thanks for leading me here Etrimaille!! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I could indeed tell you that a folder starting by a dot is a hidden folder on Mac and Linux. Great that it could work. I have edited my answer.